# How to combine two matrices in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

New to Python, struggling in numpy, hope someone can help me, thank you!

```
import numpy as np
A = np.matrix('1.0 2.0; 3.0 4.0')    
B = np.matrix('5.0 6.0; 7.0 8.0')
C = np.matrix('1.0 2.0; 5.0 6.0; 3.0 4.0; 7.0 8.0')
print "A=",A
print "B=",B
print "C=",C
```

Results:

```
A= [[ 1.  2.]
   [ 3.  4.]]
B= [[ 5.  6.]
   [ 7.  8.]]
C= [[ 1.  2.]
   [ 5.  6.]
   [ 3.  4.]
   [ 7.  8.]]
```

Question: how to use A and B to generate C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First `hstack` the matrices (so they are joined on the "x"-axis), then `reshape` to the desired shape:

```
new_C = np.hstack((A, B)).reshape(-1, 2)
print(np.all(new_C == C))
# Out: True
```

The `-1` in `reshape` means: automatically adjust the length of the first dimension ("y"-axis) such that the second dimension ("x"-axis) is reshaped to the length `2`.

The advantage over concatenating and slicing is, that it will work with matrices of **any length** of the first dimension, as long as the second dimesion has two elements. Furthermore reshaping is a quite efficient method, since generating copies is not required in many cases. Thus `hstack` + `reshape` should be much faster than three times `concatenate`.

Answer (score 0):

try this, `slicing` + [`np.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)

```
import numpy as np

A = np.matrix('1.0 2.0; 3.0 4.0')
B = np.matrix('5.0 6.0; 7.0 8.0')

even_ = np.concatenate([A[::2], B[::2]])
odd_ = np.concatenate([A[1::2], B[1::2]])

np.concatenate([even_, odd_])
```

---

```
matrix([[1., 2.],
        [5., 6.],
        [3., 4.],
        [7., 8.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

One way using `zip`:

```
np.stack(list(zip(A, B))).reshape(-1, A.shape[0])
```

Output:

```
array([[1., 2.],
       [5., 6.],
       [3., 4.],
       [7., 8.]])
```